# Ordering multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table msg(ID,TO,FROM,MSG,TIME) and I need to select distinct tuples from TO and FROM and order the result based on the latest time a message has been sent. The queries I have used so for

```
SELECT DISTINCT value 
FROM ( SELECT msg.to AS value, time 
        FROM msg 
        WHERE msg.from = '".$_SESSION["username"]."' 
    UNION 
        SELECT msg.from AS value, time 
        FROM msg 
        WHERE msg.to = '".$_SESSION["username"]."') TT 
order by time desc
```

And

```
select t1.to, t1.time 
from msg t1 
where t1.from='".$_SESSION["username"]."' 
    and t1.time=(
        select max(time) 
        from msg t2 
        where t2.to=t1.to) 
union 
select t1.from, t1.time 
from msg t1 
where t1.to='".$_SESSION["username"]."' 
    and t1.time=(
        select max(time) 
        from msg t2 
        where t2.from=t1.from)
```

But none give the desried result.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 for how to get the row with the last time in each group. Then just order the result by the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT value, max(time) as latest_time_sent
FROM ( SELECT msg.to AS value, time 
        FROM msg 
        WHERE msg.from = '".$_SESSION["username"]."' 
    UNION ALL
        SELECT msg.from AS value, time 
        FROM msg 
        WHERE msg.to = '".$_SESSION["username"]."') TT 
group by value
order by latest_time_sent desc
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the "desired result"?  How is it different from the following?

```
select TO, FROM, max(TIME) as TIME
from msg
group by TO, FROM
order by max(TIME) desc
```